# How to make id3lib works in C++ Builder 10.2?

Tags: c++, c++builder-2010, id3-tag

How to install this library in C++ Builder 10.2 on Windows 7?
I copied id3lib.dll from "id3lib-3.8.3 win binaries/debug" and put in folder with my project .exe file, than I created id3lib.lib by ImpLib (with using -a option) and added to my project. After that I linked header folder (id3) to my project and wrote `#include "id3/tag.h"`. When I'm trying to compile, I get:

> [bcc32 Fatal Error] globals.h(56): F1003 Error directive: read message
>   above or win32.readme.first.txt

What am I doing wrong to install this library?

Comment: Did you do what the error message says? Read `win32.readme.first.txt` for instructions.  You probably missed a step in the installation, such as configuring one of the library's header files for your compiler environment.

Comment: I did not follow those instructions, I used .dll from "id3lib 3.8.3 windows binaries" folder.  `win32.readme.first.txt` says, that I should create .dll, .lib by myself using `id3lib/prj` and `id3lib/libprj`.

Comment: What is the actual condition in `tag.h` that triggers the error message?

Comment: > 56     #error read message above or win32.readme.first.txt

Comment: That is not what I meant.  Clearly there is an `#error` directive in the code to make the compiler display the error message, but what *condition* causes the compiler to reach that directive in the first place?  Is there an `#if/#endif` surrounding the `#error`? And what does the "message above" say? You shouldn't make people have to hunt for this kind of information.

Comment: Nevermind, I just downloaded the source code for myself, and will post an answer.

Comment: Well, it seems like IMPLIB unable to convert id3lib.dll to proper .lib file. At least with C++ Builder 10.2 Tokyo

Answer (score 0):

There is an `#error` directive on line 56 of `globals.h`:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#  define LINKOPTION_STATIC         1 //both for use and creation of static lib
#  define LINKOPTION_CREATE_DYNAMIC 2 //should only be used by prj/id3lib.dsp
#  define LINKOPTION_USE_DYNAMIC    3 //if your project links id3lib dynamic
#  ifndef ID3LIB_LINKOPTION
#    pragma message("*** NOTICE *** (not a real error)")
#    pragma message("* You should include a define in your project which reflect how you link the library")
#    pragma message("* If you use id3lib.lib or libprj/id3lib.dsp (you link static) you should add")
#    pragma message("* ID3LIB_LINKOPTION=1 to your preprocessor definitions of your project.")
#    pragma message("* If you use id3lib.dll (you link dynamic) you should add ID3LIB_LINKOPTION=3")
#    pragma message("* to your preprocessor definitions of your project.")
#    pragma message("***")
#    error read message above or win32.readme.first.txt // <-- HERE
```

The compiler reaches the `#error` if `WIN32` is defined but `ID3LIB_LINKOPTION` is NOT defined.

As you can see in the "message above", you need to manually define `ID3LIB_LINKOPTION` in your project according to how you are linking to the ID3 library.  You have not done that yet, which is why you are getting the error.

Go into your Project Options and add an entry for `ID3LIB_LINKOPTION=3` (since you are using the DLL version of the ID3 library) in the Conditionals section.  Or, put a `#define ID3LIB_LINKOPTION 3` statement in your C++ code above any `#include` statements for ID3 header files.

Also, make sure you add your generated `id3lib.lib` file to your project using the Project Manager, or put a `#pragma comment(lib, "id3lib.lib")` directive somewhere in your C++ code.

Comment: So, it compiles successfully, but when I add an object: `ID3_Tag myTag("song.mp3");` I get the error: ** [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'ID3_Tag::~ID3_Tag()' referenced from T:\0101 PROG\PLAYER\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ.**

Comment: Any suggestions?